# How do I resolve this variant of the Knapsack Algorithm with 2 sacks?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I'm starting to study some of Algorithm. I have a question:

If you have 2 knapsacks, and a set of items with some weights (all positives), how can you solve the problem:
"Can they be equally fullfill?"  (Both with the same weight)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you have to use all items? Otherwise just put none in both.

Comment: @maraca Supposing that you need to have at least one in each bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution will be using dynamic programming with 3 states.

1. Current index on the item list
2. Weight difference
3. A bit mask ( which will represent whether I have taken at least one item in the both sack, 0 means none have a item, 3 means all the sack have at least one item )

Check this code: https://code.hackerearth.com/bdbabcZ